# How does ArrayBlockingQueue avoid shuffling array elements?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Scenario:
My producer fills the array up, say capacity new int[10], before my consumer gets a chance to consume any. My producer sees the array is full and blocks.

Then my consumer comes along and removes int[0], and signals to the producer that the array now has an empty slot to fill.

My producer wakes up, and tries to add a new element to the array. Considering only int[0] is free, and we are implementing FIFO, does ArrayBlockingQueue shuffle all the remaining 9 elements to the left, filling 0-8 indexes and leave int[9] free for the producer?

I've looked at the implementation but don't see any array copy functionality,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No copying of array elements is performed, because `ArrayBlockingQueue` uses the array as a circular buffer. It maintaining two indexes, `takeIndex` and `putIndex`, and wraps them around when they reach the end of the array.

After an operation that adds or takes an element it calls a private "increment" method called `inc`, which wraps the index around the end:

```
final int inc(int i) {
    return (++i == items.length)? 0 : i;
}
```

Here is an example of how this method is used:

```
private void insert(E x) {
    items[putIndex] = x;
    putIndex = inc(putIndex); // <<== Wraps around
    ++count;
    notEmpty.signal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayBlockingQueue` maintain two variables suppose **frontIndex** and **rearIndex** to handle this instead of shifting elements. If the queue is full. and any element is pulled up by consumer from the index **a[0]** then the **rearIndex** moved to index **1** and next time whenever producer tries to add any element **frontIndex** will be moved to the **0** index after the **9** Index. and the next put operation will be done on **a[0]**.

Here **FrontIndex==RearIndex** means the queue is full.